# Mediaplayer setNextPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I have to loop a sound in background without any gap.
I have tried many solutions like

```
SoundPool (-1 for loop)
AudioTrack
Mediaplayer
```

but did not find any best solution

now i have implemented the

```
setNextMediaPlayer()
```

like this

```
        public void createDefaultPlayer()
        {
            defaultBgSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + file, "raw", getPackageName()));
            defaultBgSound2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + file, "raw", getPackageName()));                
            defaultBgSound1.setNextMediaPlayer(defaultBgSound2);
            defaultBgSound1.start();
        }
```

it plays the next sound but i want to continue this looping for ever

any best way to loop this

Answer (score 3):

Several ideas:

1) This is how I think what you have suggested can work:

Start out exactly as you have by preparing two `MediaPlayer` instances with the same media.

Call `setNextMediaPlayer` on each passing the other as the parameter.

In the `onCompletion` callback for each, have it call `stop()` and `prepareAsync()` on itself. This should return it to the prepared state, which I believe is what the `setNextMediaPlayer` mechanism expects. If the sound is a local resource and of sufficient duration, there should not be a problem with this approach, although you can use the `onPrepared` callback to help check timing if there is.

Alternatively, you can try simply calling `seekTo(0)` in the `onCompletion` callback, which should be quicker than the `stop()/prepareAsync()` method. However, I think that may not work properly with `setNextMediaPlayer` as it leaves the `MediaPlayer` in the completed state. (I'm not sure because I've never tried this.)

I don't think the next `MediaPlayer` will get un-set, thus I don't think you will need to call `setNextMediaPlayer` more than once per instance. But if you do, use the `onPrepared` callback to have each `MediaPlayer` set the other as its next player.

2) Use one `MediaPlayer` and call `seekTo(0)` and `start()` in the `onCompletion` callback. I would assume this is what happens when the player is looping, but I'm not sure about that. It may be worth a shot.

3) Learn OpenSL and implement your own player in native code. This approach is much more research intensive, but provides the greatest control :)

Comment: thanks dave, i have tried many of them but have not tried seekto

Comment: That did not work in that way which i want that is not smooth