# Issue with audio playback using setNextMediaPlayer

Tags: android, loops, android-mediaplayer

I need to play an audio without gaps between lopping, the audio needs to be looped forever without gaps. Using `setNextMediaPlayer` only merge two audio tracks without gaps, after that it automatically stops playing the audio, it is not looping for ever. Thanks in advance.

```
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.loop);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.loop);

protected void play() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mp1.start();
    mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
    // mp2.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);

}
```

Comment: Hi Sai, I am also having a similar issue. For some reason, the 2nd Media Player is not playing the video (only the sound). Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to help a guy do that just a few days ago. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968133/mediaplayer-setnextplayer/19968502#19968502).

I'm not sure if he was able to achieve what he wanted, but I believe your problem is that the `MediaPlayer` is not in the prepared state after the 2nd track finishes. You will need to use the `onCompletion` listener to return it to the prepared state by calling `stop()` and `prepareAsync()`. If it doesn't need to be in the prepared state (I'm honestly not sure), it would be faster to call `seekTo(0)` from the `onCompletion` listener.

You will definitely need to uncomment the `mp2.setNextMediaPlayer(mp1);` line.