# IllegalStateException while trying to set 3rd player via setNextMediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

There are 3 `MediaPlayer`s and I want to set that these 3 sounds play seamlessly using `setNextMediaPlayer()`. The code is simple (repeated code is omitted)

```
    mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("sound1.ogg");
        mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer1.prepare();
        afd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer1.start();

    mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
    //Prepare 2nd player with sound2 without calling start()

    mediaPlayer3 = new MediaPlayer();
    //Prepare 3rd player with sound3 without calling start()

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        mediaPlayer1.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer2);
        mediaPlayer2.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer3); //ERROR RUNTIME!!!
```

And here I get an error

> E/MediaPlayer﹕ next player is not prepared
>   D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4175fda0)
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.testgaplesssound.app, PID: 28960
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.IllegalStateException at...

The error say `MediaPlayer﹕ next player is not prepared` so I tried setting onPrepared listener

```
  mediaPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              mediaPlayer2.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer3);                                    
        }
  }
  });
```

but onPrepared is never initiated!

So, how can I sent the 3rd player to play seamlessly as the first two?

Comment: Are you sure the initializations for `mediaPlayer3` aren't throwing an Exception?

Comment: Yes, even without it it breaks on the same line. I found other sources that other guys are experiencing the same not prepared illegalstate error. Try it yourself if you have 5min. You will get the same error.

Comment: @MikeM. Did you manage to test this? Do you get the same error?

Comment: May I ask why you're not using the `MediaPlayer.create(Context, int)` method to instantiate your players, instead of using asset file descriptors?

Comment: Also, why are you starting `mediaPlayer1` before initializing and chaining the other two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the following setup with no errors, thinking your problem was with initialization. But then I noticed that you're starting your first player before initializing and chaining the other two. Reordering your code might solve your problem, but I'll post this as well, as it seems a simpler solution, to me, at least.

Move your audio files to the `/res/raw` folder, and initialize and start your players like so:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1, mediaPlayer2, mediaPlayer3;

mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
mediaPlayer1.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer2);
mediaPlayer2.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer3);

mediaPlayer1.start();
```

NB: I tested under API 19, so you'll still need your version checks, if you're back-supporting.

Comment: OMG I can't believe it was due to initialization :). BTW, does it work in your case if you instead of `mediaPlayer3` put `mediaPlayer1` (create loop)?

Comment: I did a quick test, but that didn't work for me. A search less me to this answer, however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034519/issue-with-audio-playback-using-setnextmediaplayer